# On running pgxn install -> Getting ERROR: network error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

Installed PGXN using  `pip install pgxnclient`

Tried installing the postgres extension `pgxn_utils` using PGXN client

- https://pgxn.org/dist/pgxn_utils/0.1.4/

On running the command `pgxn install pgxn_utils`
getting the Error:

```
ERROR: network error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer that worked for me, it appears i had not yet installed the python certificates on my mac, so from the following path i went and installed it

`/Applications/Python 3.11/Install Certificates.command`

Only change the version of your python, after that everything, worked fine for me